# Unable to find expected entry 'main/source/Sources' in Release file

Tags: apt, updates, wine, ppa, update-manager

```
$ sudo apt-get update                 
Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease                
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease       
Reading package lists... Done                      

E : Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease      
Unable to find expected entry 'main/source/Sources' in Release file 
  (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way :

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. enter `software-properties-gtk` here
3. in *Software & Updates* go to *Other Software* tab
4. find `dl.winehq.org` here
5. uncheck mark near `https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial main (Source Code)` (or similar).
6. Then reload package lists.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your sources.list?
 Post the output of

```
sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

How have you added the WineHQ Source?

Have you tried following this: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu ?